# why window.open always pop up with IE

Tags: window.open

`window.open()`why window.open always pop up with IE ,
I set firefox is the default browser,
but still pop up with IE ?
why is that ?how to pop up with firefox?or chrome?

Comment: You're calling `window.open` in Javascript code on a webpage, correct? The opened window will open in the same browser the page containing the script was opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because IE is defined as your default browser.

Comment: there is a button in winform, when I click the button, it runs window.open ,witch pop up with IE, there is no way pop up with other browser when i click the button ??????

Answer (score 3):

if your parent window is IE,then it open with IE,when you call it with chrome,it pop up chrome window.